# Understanding Android's Wifi State

Tags: android, networking

I need to check if my device is connected to a wifi network. But the events that occur confuse me. Here are the steps to reproduce:

## registerReceiver

So I registered a receiver with the action `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)`:

```
private void registerReceiver() {
    Log.v(TAG, "registerReceiver");

    final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);

    broadcastReceiver = new ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver();
    context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
}
```

## onReceive

And this is how I receive the events.

```
private class ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v("Broadcast", "onReceive: " + intent.getAction());
        final NetworkInfo networkInfo =
                intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

        if (networkInfo != null) {
            final NetworkInfo.State state = networkInfo.getState();
            final NetworkInfo.DetailedState detailedState = networkInfo.getDetailedState();

            Log.d(TAG, "NetworkInfo.State: " + state);
            Log.d(TAG, "NetworkInfo.DetailedState: " + detailedState);
        }

        final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        final WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

        final SupplicantState supplicantState = wifiInfo.getSupplicantState();
        final NetworkInfo.DetailedState detailedState = wifiInfo.getDetailedStateOf(supplicantState);

        Log.d(TAG, "SupplicantState: " + supplicantState.toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "DetailedStateOfSupplicant: " + detailedState.toString());
    }
}
```

## User Input

1. I start the app, pull the Android menu down from above, open wifi settings (by holding the wifi symbol) and connect to a wifi network. I then return back to my app.

or

2. I start the app, pull the Android menu down from above, active wifi from the quick settings. I then return back to my app. My device automatically connects to a known wifi.

## Output

First I receive some events about `CONNECTING` and `AUTHENTICATING`. Everything seems to be normal here.

But then I get this output **four times** in a row during **one setup**:

```
onReceive: Broadcast android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
NetworkInfo.State: CONNECTED
NetworkInfo.DetailedState: CONNECTED
SupplicantState: COMPLETED
DetailedStateOfSupplicant: OBTAINING_IPADDR
```

1. Why are these four events triggered?

That the supplicant state `COMPLETED` gets mapped to `OBTAINING_IPADDR` seems logic according to the documentation:

> SupplicantState COMPLETED:
>   This state indicates that the supplicant has completed its processing
>   for the association phase and that data connection is fully
>   configured. Note, however, that there may not be any IP address
>   associated with the connection yet. Typically, a DHCP request needs to
>   be sent at this point to obtain an address.

2. But why is the network info state and even the detailed state set to `CONNECTED` if my device is actually just obtaining it's IP address?
3. How can I ensure that my device is "really" connected, in other words, how do I know when my device finally obtained it's IP address and when the network is ready for use? Is there a better action that I can register upon?

## Sources

- An overview of `NetworkInfo.State` and `NetworkInfo.DetailedState` can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.State.html).
- An overview of `SupplicantState` can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/SupplicantState.html).

Answer (score 2):

Check network state using the below class:

```
 public class Connectivity {
    public static NetworkInfo getNetworkInfo(Context context){
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    }


    public static boolean isConnected(Context context){
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected());
    }

    public static boolean isConnectedWifi(Context context){
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    }


    public static boolean isConnectedMobile(Context context){
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    }


    public static boolean isConnectedFast(Context context){
        NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
        return (info != null && info.isConnected() && Connectivity.isConnectionFast(info.getType(),info.getSubtype()));
    }


    public static boolean isConnectionFast(int type, int subType){
        if(type== ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
            return true;
        }else if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
            switch(subType){
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
                    return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
                    return false; // ~ 14-64 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
                    return false; // ~ 50-100 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_0:
                    return true; // ~ 400-1000 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_A:
                    return true; // ~ 600-1400 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
                    return false; // ~ 100 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
                    return true; // ~ 2-14 Mbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
                    return true; // ~ 700-1700 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
                    return true; // ~ 1-23 Mbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
                    return true; // ~ 400-7000 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EHRPD: // API level 11
                    return true; // ~ 1-2 Mbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO_B: // API level 9
                    return true; // ~ 5 Mbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPAP: // API level 13
                    return true; // ~ 10-20 Mbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_IDEN: // API level 8
                    return false; // ~25 kbps
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE: // API level 11
                    return true; // ~ 10+ Mbps
                // Unknown
                case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There seems to be a bug... when you call `isConnectedWifi()` right after a wifi event occurred because of a new established wifi connection, then `getActiveNetworkInfo()` returns null because Android wasn't able to switch the default in that time

Comment: For those case, you have to implement Networks state change listener. This class not able to handle it.